# Smarty format date to HTML5 <time /> spec

Tags: php, date, datetime, smarty, html

I am nearly there all I need it the last Time Zone

```
<time datetime="{$row.datetime.value|date_format:"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"}"></time>
<time datetime="2011-07-11T00:00:00GMT Daylight Time"></time>
```

I need this to work by adding +01:00 like this: 2011-07-11T00:00:00+01:00 otherwise when I validate the page I get invalid date errors.

[Looking at the doc page](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl) it doesn't

Comment: Are you ever going to display times from other time zones? You can hard code the "+01:00" there.

Comment: For now it will just be the one timezone although I would prefer for this to be worked out dynamically. In the PHP manual it says I need /z although this doesn't work for smarty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

```
<time datetime="{date('c', $row.datetime.value)}"></time>
```

### Alternative

Yes, I know that it's a non-standard way of calling functions. If you don't like it, you can write a Smarty plugin.

```
<?php
    function smarty_modifier_standard_time($timestamp) {
        return date("c", $timestamp);
    }
?>
```

then save this plugin as modifier.standard_time.php in plugins directory and then call it like this:

```
{$row.datetime.value|standard_time}
```

Comment: This give me error:
Fatal error: Smarty error: [in news.tpl line 17]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: date('c', $row.datetime.value) (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 446) in C:\php\includes\smarty\libs\Smarty.class.php on line 1092

Comment: I tried creating a plugin but it doesn't recognise the plugin. I am working with an old version of smarty 2 I think

Comment: Yes, using Smarty 2 will give you this syntax error, but Smarty 3 is a lot better, so try to upgrade. If you can't / won't: I've edited my solution, it had a bug, now I changed the plugin to a modifier and should now work.